# Filter notification with day of week

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I have a problem with the alarm and notifications. I set up notifications that arrive locally to a acerta now, and up there no problem. I tried to make the user choose which days to get a notification with a shared preferences in the settings, and get them as you see in the code. but this does not work, even if I decide one day there's also all other notifications without distinction, can not figure out what wrong. Can someone help me? thank you all.

I must refresh the alarm?

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("SETTING_NOTIFICATION", MODE_PRIVATE);

     calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("lun", true)){
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        notifi();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "notification lunedi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("mar", true)){
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        notifi();
    }
    if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("mer", true)){
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        notifi();
    }
    if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("gio", true)){
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 3);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        notifi();
    }
    if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("ven", true)){
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 4);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        notifi();
    }
    if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("sab", true)){
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        notifi();
    }
    if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("dom", true)){
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        notifi();
    }

}


public void notifi(){
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Home.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Home.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) Home.this.getSystemService(Home.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);


}
```